# How to deliver data to iPhone app instantly?

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode10

I'm developing an app for our security company, that needs to receive alarm events in a matter of seconds. So this is the main event flow:

- An alarm goes on in one of the buildings
- Our server gets that alarm info immediately
- Server distributes the alarm message straight to the app of
  responsible person
- app starts beeping, until the responsible person doesn't interact
  with the app and sends a "message received" status back to the server
- location tracking of the person is triggered, and data being sent to the server.

I tried using APNs, but the delivery time there $uck$. Since this data should be delivered ASAP, I'm wondering if someone has any clue, how to deliver some data to the iPhone in realtime?

I see PushKit is available, but only for VoIP applications, which this isn't. And the app wont pass the approval in the AppStore if I use that.

Any pointer will be welcome!
Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't really depend on APNs, matter of fact all notifications for iOS devices goes  trough APNs including PushKit. This is the API that is use for one of my trading apps: https://pusher.com/docs/beams/getting-started/ios/configure-apns

Answer (score 0):

Please note that all Push Notification services must go through APNS, and APNS is the fastest method since it is socket-based, for any other way without push notifications, you need to setup a socket listener on your server and handle the socket on the client using SocketIO for example, this is the fastest method for real time interactions.

And you can use a cron job to fetch data by API each X seconds for example, but it is not fast or real-time as socket-based platform.